# Listar 3 campos a partir de um Array

Tags: php, html

Olá, tudo bom?

estou com uma dúvida.

Quero listar, uma lista de contatos, mas não consigo fazer o echo no array, vocês poderiam me ajudar?

esse é meu código:

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Lista de contatos</legend>
            <label for="name">
                Nome:
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="name">
            </label><br>
            <label for="tel">
                telefone:
                <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel">
            </label><br>
            <label for="email">
                E-mail:
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php 
           $contatos = [];

            if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)) {
                $contatos['nome'][] = $_GET['nome'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists('tel', $_GET)) {
                $contatos['tel'][] = $_GET['tel'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists('email',$_GET)) {
                $contatos['email'][] = $_GET['email'];
            }
    ?>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>telefone</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($contatos as $contato) : ?>
            <?php print_r($contato); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>

            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Não estou conseguindo identificar o problema no foreach, tentei por diversas vezes a principio só quero listar o nome, pois se consigo listar o nome, os outros campos seguirão a mesma lógica.

Comment: Se você quer exibir apenas o que for enviado via $_GET, não vejo necessidade de usar array, basta:
....
  if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)) {
                $nome = $_GET['nome'];
  } 
....
 <td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem o array multidimensional `$contatos` que está armazenando as informaçãoes `nome, tel e email`:

```
if (array_key_exists('chave', $_GET)) {
    $contatos['chave'][] = $_GET['nome'];
}
```

Dessa forma o `foreach($contatos as $key=>$value)` esta dizendo que, para cada contato vc tem as chaves `nome, tel e email` que contem, por sua vez, um array com as informações representado por `$value`:

```
foreach($contatos as $key=>$value):
    //código
endforeach;
```

Porém para acessar as informações do `$value` que também é um array vc precisa de outro loop ou de acesso direto as chaves;

Como não sei a demanda, o que posso fazer é perguntar se há necessidade de `$contatos["chave"][]` ser um array?

> Resolução:

Você pode tirar esse array `[]` de `$contatos["chave"]` e seguir com seu código ou fazer um loop

```
foreach($contatos as $key=>$value):
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){
        echo $value[$i];
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!